# .lis files generated while compiling Pro*C code in Linux

Tags: linux

when I compile Pro*C codes in Linux, in addition to .c and .o files, .lis files are also generated. But the .lis files were not generated when I compiled the same set of codes in Unix.
Any idea why .lis files are generated in Linux but not in Unix?

The compiler which I use in LINUX is gcc 4.1.2

Comment: We use Pro*C under Linux, Solaris, AIX and HP/UX and .lis files are generated for all these platforms.  Perhaps different options are being passed to the Pro*C compiler?