# zero byte .lis files generated in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc

I am using gcc 4.1.2 in Linux to compile C/Pro*C codes. At the end of makefile run, I find that for every source code compiled, a corresponding zero byte file with extension .lis is generated. (but the compilation completes without any errors/warnings)
But when the same makefile is run on solaris, the .lis files are not generated. what may be the cause of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195707/lis-files-generated-while-compiling-proc-code-in-linux

Comment: Hi, the link says it may be due to compiler options. But what specific compiler options are used? Since the .lis files are too many in number, i do not want the files to be generated.

Comment: something like "-source_listing" in your makefile?

Comment: no my make file does not have any command to generate .lis files. I know this is weird but the fact!

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature of newer versions of Pro*C.

You can suppress it by setting the `LTYPE=NONE` [preprocessor option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_10opt.htm).